# How to use @types/express-session?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, express-session

when I write this:

```
import { Request } from 'express-serve-static-core';

router.post((req: Request, res, next) => {
  req.session.user = user;
}
```

`tsc` gives me an error:

> 'Object is possibly 'undefined'.

I know the original `Request` type does not have the `session` field.

I check `@types/express-session` `index.d.ts` file, found this:

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      session?: Session;
      sessionID?: string;
    }
  //....
}
```

So I want to add extra field `session` and `sessionID` type to the `req`.

How can I use ? like this: `req: Request & ExpressSessionRequest`.

So the `req` will have both original `Request` type and extra fields type which `@types/express-session` add.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is not that `Request` does not have the `session` or `sessionID` properties -- the typings for `express-session` already adds the properties to `Request` interface via [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces).

The error comes from turning the `strictNullChecks` compiler option on. Since the properties `session` is declared as nullable in the type definition, the compiler warns you exactly that. If you are sure that `req.session` is not null of undefined, you can use the [not-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) (`!`) to suppress the error:

```
router.post((req: Request, res, next) => {
    req!.session!.user = user;
})
```

Or check for null|undefined explicitly:

```
router.post((req: Request, res, next) => {
    if (req.session) {
        req.session.user = user;
    }
})
```

---

If you want to make the `session` and `sessionID` properties non-nullable, then you can write your own custom type:

```
type YourSessionRequest = Request & {
    session: Express.Session;
    sessionID: string;
}
router.post((req: YourSessionRequest, res, next) => {
    req.session.user = user;
})
```

Comment: yes. my mistake. I forget the `session` and `sessionID` are optional properties. But does it make sense? I always think the `session` and `sessionID` properties are always exist on `req` when use `express-session` .

Comment: I am not sure `express-session`. If the `session` and `sessionID` properties always exist then the typings need to be updated. If you want to override the properties yourself, you can try the option in my updated answer.