# Using ExpressJS Session in Typescript

Tags: typescript, express

While using typescript in ExpressJS... I've run into many problems, one of then is me trying to access data in the *request* and *response* parameters provided by third party middleware such as express-session.

I have this code here:

```js
import express, {
    Application,
    Request,
    Response
} from 'express';


const cli:Application = express();

cli.set('trust proxy', true);
cli.use(require('cookie-parser')());
cli.use(require('express-session')({secret: 'Help me!'}));

cli.get('/invites/:invite', (req:Request, res:Response) => {
    if (req.params.invite){
        req.session.code = req.params.invite;
        console.log(req.session.code);
        res.send(req.session.code);
  
    }
});
```

when I put this code in my IDE I get this error:
[image: error]

I have already attempted the fix using the extended interface:

```js
interface WithSession extends Request {
    session: any
}

cli.get('/invites/:invite', (req:WithSession, res:Response) => {
    if (req.params.invite){
        req.session.code = req.params.invite;
        console.log(req.session.code);
        res.send(req.session.code);
  
    }
});
```

but my IDE still gives errors:
[image: err2]
If there is any way to fix this please let me know!

Thanks for reading my problem, I hope you can solve it!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to install `@types/express-session`, and possibly to turn off strict null checks. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45830015/how-to-use-types-express-session) for more discussion.